# Executing multiprocess python script from another python script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gil

I have two python scripts, script A and script B.  My environment is Linux with the CPython implementation.

At some point in script A use Process from multiprocessing to start multiple processes using the normal `p.start()` and `p.join()` procedure.

Script B calls script A in the following way:

```
subprocess.call(["python", "script_A.py"])
```

When I run script A by itself, it uses all the cores that I ask it to use.

When I run script A from script B, only one core is used, no matter what. How can I call script A from script B and have it use all the cores that I ask it to use?

Comment: Do you mean you're using the `multiprocessing` library? What platform is this on? Can you share the `subprocess` call you're making? And are you by any chance using `numpy` in script B?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935836/can-a-python-script-know-that-another-instance-of-the-same-script-is-running

Comment: @AvinashBabu Not sure what that has to do with this question.

Comment: am like confused ..i didnt get the question properly so i gave a link to the question which is similar

Comment: @ASDF I would expect script A to use all cores no matter what. There's only one explanation I can think of: If script B is using `numpy`, the processor affinity may be getting changed in script B in a way that will prevent `multiprocessing` from using more than one core (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15647474/2073595) for more info). If that's the case, I think the processor affinity of script B will be inherited by script A, which will cause the behavior you're seeing. If you're not using `numpy`, I have no idea what's causing the issue.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove references to multithreading, because that's not what's going on here. Also, do your calls to `p.start()` explicitly specify a number of processes, or do you leave it up to the default argument?

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks for the edits. @dano: That was exactly what was going on with `numpy`. Thanks a lot.